# Trying to read data from a text file and populating a list of integers

Tags: clojure

So, upfront, I'm super new at Clojure so this question may seem basic.  I hava a txt file with 1 line that has a set number of intergers separated by a space.  I need to read that data and populate a list so I can sort it later.  I'm not asking how to do the sort, I need help populating the list with the string from the txt file.

My initial thought is to read the entire line of ints as one string, then split the string with a delimiter, and populate the list with the returned data, but I cant figure out how to do that in clojure.  Any guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it, using some [helper functions](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo).  Be sure to also bookmark:

- [The Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html)
- [Brave Clojure](https://www.braveclojure.com/)
- [Getting Clojure](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/getting-clojure/9781680506082/)

---

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [schema.core :as s]
    [clojure.string :as str]))

(dotest
  (let [filename "/tmp/dummy.txt"]
    (spit filename "1 2 3   4 5")
    (let-spy
      [in-str   (slurp filename)
       nums-str (str/split in-str #"\W+")
       nums     (mapv #(Integer/parseInt %) nums-str)]
      )))
```

with result:

```
-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.0    Java 12
-------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
in-str => "1 2 3   4 5"
nums-str => ["1" "2" "3" "4" "5"]
nums => [1 2 3 4 5]
```